# Powering circuit from PC's USB port, where to place the LDO?

Tags: microcontroller, power, usb, ftdi

I am working on a circuit connected to computer via FTDI FT232RL. There are some op-amps and an MCU in the circuit. Total power consumption (including FTDI chip) approx. 0.4 Watt/h. My op-amps need 5V voltage (single supply) well regulated. It's time to design the power supply.

There are USB-V+, FT232RL-Vcc and MCU-Vcc. The question is, how should I use the USB's V+ pin for feeding the op-amp circuit?

First, is it good to connect USB-V+ to LDO (regulator IC) like AMS1117 and power all (FTDI, MCU and Op-amps) with regulated output of AMS1117?

1-) USB-V+ --> AMS1117 --> FTDI+ MCU + Op-amps

Second, connecting USB-V+ to FTDI and getting LDO output after that is any better?

2-) USB-V+ --> FTDI --> AMS1117 --> MCU + Op-amps

Comment: Read this note: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=Y5XLVJyVCfOHsQTpo4KgAw&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt118/slyt118.pdf&ved=0CCQQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNFEpEAFb2kmoy3Oz0jvOulg8o3uJQ&sig2=Y0epc_jKPS8J7Zich3tFRQ ... If your current draw is only 80 mA it should be ok to use a USB 2.0 port as those can supply up to 500 mA. Just make sure your linear regulator is efficient. I don't know enough about your design to recommend one configuration over the other though.

Comment: mA/h is not a unit of power consumption.

Comment: @OlinLathrop mA/h is current consumption right? But 5V-80mA can be said as power consumption maybe.

Comment: @pikafu What is wrong with not efficient regulator? Is it dangerous or bad for another ICs?

Comment: @user30878 - power is voltage times current. mAh is a unit of charge, which is current times time. To get watt-hours you times amp-hours by the voltage of the system. Amp-hours are used for batteries mainly, because the voltage of the battery changes as the battery charge changes. Your system draws 80 mA and is run at ~5V so it consumes 0.4 Watts. No need to use Watt-hours since a watt-hour merely means the system expends a watt constantly for an hour.

Comment: @I.Wolfe I don't understand exactly. But I changed the question as you said.

Comment: Any reason you can't just avoid the regulators and run directly off the USB power?  After all, your computer (including audio system) does.  Could you just use an LC filter to smooth it if necessary, or some additional low ESR capacitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XX1117 is not really an LDO regulator, more of a medium-drop-out.

You need to give it quite a bit more input voltage than you expect out of it. So if your circuitry is happy with 3V (say), you may be okay. You can only count on 4.35V at the USB connector, and the regulator can use as much as 1.3V depending on current etc. so that leaves you with 3.05V. At 80mA, 3.3V may be acceptable, but you'll have to sharpen your pencil to figure that out.

If you want to create a low-noise well-regulated 5V supply from a USB input, you would have to boost the input to something like 5.5V and use a true LDO or to more like 6.5V and use an XX1117 regulator. At 80% efficiency that means you'd be at about 150mA input current. That's acceptable, but you're supposed to negotiate for current above 100mA. Possibly the FTDI chip does that for you. If you're dealing with two supply voltages in your system you may have to have voltage translators and so on, and the details will vary a lot depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Maybe you can operate all the digital stuff from the USB Vcc and use regulated 3.0V or 3.3V for the analog stuff. That would be my first plan of attack.

Comment: Another question but small for being new: Does USB Vcc is stable enough to feed op-amps?

Comment: Maybe- depends on the requirements.